# Не могу запустить нужную версию python. Windows 10 запускает 3.8.5 вместо 3.9.1

Tags: python

Все началось с того что я захотел [помигать светодиодом](https://youtu.be/5IuZ-E8Tmhg?t=309) с помощью esp32 и С++

но как всегда что-то пошло не так.
При попытке запустить терминал, настроенный по учебнику, я получил

> pkg_resources cannot be imported probably because the pip package is not installed and/or using a legacy Python interpreter. Please refer to the Get Started section of the ESP-IDF Programming Guide for setting up the required packages.

наверное надо обновить пип
wir+r=>cmd=>python

> Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 09:26:39)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ">>>"

pip --version

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  NameError: name 'pip' is not defined

Окей гугл, как обновить пип.

> поставь новый питон и не мучайся

качаем. ставим. О. и пип в комплекте и path прописать. лепота.
wir+r=>cmd=>python

> Python **3.8.5** (default, Sep  4 2020, 09:26:39)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ">>>"

установка удаление программ. точно два питона. правда удалить...
В итоге я бился как чайка о скалы часа три. в попытках вытереть пайтон 3.8.5 из виндовса. Устанавливал, удалял оба, ползал по реестру. и тд. В переменной path стоит только python 3.9. В итоге я вообще не знаю что делать.

Как объяснить виндовсу, что у меня последний питон, как объяснить VisualCode что у меня последний питон и пип работает

Comment: я решил переустановить esp-idf. и во время установки он спрашивает какая версия питона доступна. и вот она свежеустановленная 3.9

Comment: заходим в папку windows. запускаем py.exe запускается Python 3.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вопрос в гугл "[How can I find where Python is installed on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows)"

```
cmd
C:\Users\admin>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 09:26:39)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin'
>>>
```

UPD спустя n-часов. В итоге я удалил ВСЁ что похоже на Python. Установил 3.9.1
и все равно он мне говорит что пипа нет.

Заходим в виндовые настройки. в поиске вводим "переменн"
у меня два  результата "изменение переменных среды текущего пользователя" откроется окно "переменные среды"
"изменение системных переменных среды" откроются "свойства системы" и внизу нужно ткнуть "переменные среды"
По идее у вас уже должна в верхней части быть переменная path. "изменить"
"создать" и добавляем путь до папки в которой лежит pip с:/bla/bla/bla/Python39/scripts

```
C:\Users\admin>pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```